# are multi-qubit controlled Z gates (CZ,CCZ,CCZ,...) symmetric

Tags: quantum-gate

The CZ gate is known to be symmetric : $CZ(a;b)=CZ(b;a)$;

what about $CCZ(a,b;t) \stackrel{?}{=} CCZ(a,t;b) \stackrel{?}{=} CCZ(t,a;b) \cdots $

same question for $CCCZ$ gates..

I think the answer is yes, but I'd like to see a reference or better yet a nice way to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A $\mathsf C Z$ gate rotates the phase of $|11\rangle$, and does nothing to the three other basis states.

A $\mathsf C^{n-1}Z$ gate will rotate the phase of the $|11\ldots 1\rangle$ state, and will do nothing to the $2^n-1$ other states.

If *any* of the $n$ qubits are $|0\rangle$, no phasing occurs.

Therefore such gates are symmetric and invariant under permutation of the qubit indices.  For $n=2$, we often emphasize this by circuit diagrams having the $\mathsf C Z$ gate be symmetric.

Comment: seems so obvious now...nice argument